# /dev/vda1 is consuming too much space - no space left on device

Tags: disk-space-utilization

I am facing a problem during a web service deployment.
The web service runs in a docker container and the first couple of times it started and worked properly.

Last time during the load of the image I received the "no space left on device" error message.
I checked the disk space and overlay2 and /dev/vda1 were almost full (9.7 GB/10 GB)
I removed all the docker images and containers.
In order to clean docker the `docker system prune --all --volumes --force` command was applied.

Then I checked the space used by docker and it was 0 (see the print screen below).

[image: Space used by docker]

Unfortunately /dev/vda1 still has the same size (see the result of disk space inspection) and I am getting the same "no space left on device" error message.

[image: Disk space]

Since I have uploaded only docker images I suppose that this folder is docker related.

Do you have any idea how I can get rid of this wasted disk space?

Answer (score 1):

Reboot.

Files that are open are left in place (but with no visible file name), so killing the process will let the space be reclaimed. A reboot is the simplest way to ensure that all dangling references are removed.

Comment: Dear vidarlo,
Thanks for your answer.
It took some time, but I have just restarted the server.
Unfortunately the problem still persist (i.e. the size of /dev/vda1 is 9.9 GB).
Do you have any other idea?
Best Regards, Tibor

Comment: Why do you expect the size of `vda1` to change?

Comment: I can not use the server. I am continuously getting the error message: "no space left on device".